# Question to people who work with Angular apps,what kind of private npm repository exist?

Tags: angular

Here is what I'm looking for: I need a software to run a repo and a software which is a local repo to pull modules.

1. My client need a solution for NPM repository madness, they want to store locally all required java script library's and then later review it for security and put it for developers so they pull those library s first.
2. To establish a maintainable and stable state of this repo, it should be possible to run tests against the external library(s).
3. It should be opensource products, meaning no further investment planed